# Move an image after button click

Tags: objective-c, interface

i programmatically insert a custom botton (image) in xCode. After a click on the UIbutton i want to move the button to a custom place on the iPhone screen.

The programmatically button:

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

    UIButton *MyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:nil];

    MyButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 170, 100, 30);

    [MyButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tap.png"] forState:nil];

    [self.view addSubview:MyButton];

    [MyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

i'm trying to move the button after a click.

```
-(void)buttonPressed {
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed!");


    CGRect frame = MyButton.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 100; // new x coordinate
    frame.origin.y = 4; // new y coordinate

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.1];
    MyButton.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
```

but nothing nothings happens.

I the `.h` file

```
IBOutlet UIButton *MyButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *MyButton;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to use an `UIButton`, because they already listen for tap events. Otherwise you will need to add an `UIGestureRecognizer` to your UIImageView. Once you have your `UIButton` set up in Interface Builder and connected to an IBOutlet, you can use this same code to move it.

**EDIT**

Your problem may be that you are creating a new button instead of assigning to your MyButton property. Instead of:

```
UIButton *MyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:nil];
```

try:

```
MyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; // UIButtonTypeCustom is what you would need to properly display your image. If you aren't setting an image for the button yet, then instead try UIButtonTypeRoundedRect.
```

Comment: Whoops sorry the image is a costum UIbutton

Comment: Can you extrapolate on the exact issue you are having? It looks like you are very close.